# Are there pitfalls of extending a partition to a space before it in Windows 7 (after Windows 10 upgrade)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, partitioning, windows-10-upgrade, disk-management

Several years ago, it was impossible to extend a partition to a space directly *before* it, using Windows 7's built-in Disk Management ([case #1 from 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/134994/extend-windows-7-partition-to-use-free-space-before-it), [case #2 from 2012](https://superuser.com/questions/491616/is-it-safe-to-expand-my-partition-unallocated-space-before-the-partition)).

This **has been possible for several years now**, since I've done it twice: several years ago (G:) and today (E:).

Unfortunately, *while* the process seems to work just fine, and I haven't had any problems with the extended partition so far, and the Explorer detects the size correctly, and the list in the top half of Disk Management shows everything's fine (*Zdrowy* means *Healthy* in Polish)...

[image: top half of a Disk Management window (in Polish, Windows 7), showing a detailed list describing 4 completely healthy partitions: E:, C:, G:, and Restricted by System]

...when you look at diagram in the bottom half of Disk, the extended partitions (G: and E:) appear bisected, and that just looks... ***OMINOUS***.

[image: bottom half of a Disk Management window (in Polish, Windows 7), showing a visual diagram of the same 4 partitions; now E: and G: appear bisected]

I have ignored this as some quirk of Windows 7, but I'm upgrading to Windows 10 soon, and now I'm starting to worry this is something that will backfire in Windows 10.
(And I can't backup the entire partition, format it, and put all the files back in.)

Are those partitions going to cause problems after the upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: I took a peek at the disks via Ubuntu Live USB, and turns out other systems just see them as two separate partitions, so the worst thing that could happen is that the added space will revert to either another partition or empty space. I will report what happens in Windows 10 after the upgrade.

Comment: Note for future answer: Windows 7 *does* threat the new half as a single partition: if you try to remove it, it will remove the whole volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no *apparent* pitfalls.

Windows 10 shows the exact same configuration.

(Curiously, Ubuntu sees the bisected partitions as two separate partitions.)